# Pandas count frequencies within str series

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Given a Pandas Series of type str, I want to get the frequencies of the result returned by str.split.

For example, given the Series

```
s = pd.Series(['abc,def,ghi','ghi,abc'])
```

I would like to get

```
abc: 2
def: 1
ghi: 2
```

as a result. How can I get this?

**Edit:** The solution should efficiently work with a large Series of 50 million rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another pandas solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) :

```
print pd.Series(s.str.split(',').sum()).value_counts()
abc    2
ghi    2
def    1
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

More efficent methods:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['abc,def,ghi','ghi,abc'])
s = pd.concat([s]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [17]: %timeit pd.Series(s.str.split(',').sum()).value_counts()
1 loops, best of 3: 3.1 s per loop

In [18]: %timeit s.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
10 loops, best of 3: 46.2 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([ x.split(',') for x in s.tolist() ]).stack().value_counts()
10 loops, best of 3: 22.2 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit pd.Series([item for sublist in [ x.split(',') for x in s.tolist() ] for item in sublist]).value_counts()
100 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: `pd.Series(s.str.split(',').sum()).value_counts()` - this one is nice!

Comment: Thanks, MaxU. Nice day.

Comment: The call to `sum()` seems to be really slow on a large data frame of 50 million rows. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

is that what you want?

```
In [29]: from collections import Counter

In [30]: Counter(s.str.split(',').sum())
Out[30]: Counter({'abc': 2, 'def': 1, 'ghi': 2})
```

or

```
In [34]: a = pd.Series(s.str.split(',').sum())

In [35]: a
Out[35]:
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
3    ghi
4    abc
dtype: object

In [36]: a.groupby(a).size()
Out[36]:
abc    2
def    1
ghi    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you very much! I've been thinking about this for quite some time!

Comment: @David, always glad to help! :)

Comment: Actually, it seems more difficult than initially thought. I'm working with a large series with about 50 million rows. However, the call to `sum()` seems to be really slow. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @David, hmmm... how long does it take with 50M rows?